# Hide some opportunity record types, but still allow reporting

Tags: reporting, sharing

The main goal was to create a new opportunity record type and have it be visible to only certain profiles. I was able to accomplish this, but the way I did it made it so that some profiles can no longer run opportunity reports. But they still need to be able to run opportunity reports.

First on all profiles I hid all read/write access to opportunities. Then I created a sharing rule saying some profiles can read/write RecordType1 and another rule saying some profiles can read/write RecordType2.

This causes everyone to be able to see and edit records they should be able to see, except none of them can run an opportunity report, including custom opportunity report types. If I add just the basic Read access for opportunities to a profile it now will see all of the opportunity again, and be able to run reports.

Is there a way to limit which opportunities are visible but still allow reporting on opportunities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your Organization Wide Defaults for Opportunities to Private. The Profiles themselves must have at least Read, Create, and Edit permissions to allow users to edit Opportunity records. Finally, your Sharing Rules should allow users to edit the appropriate records.

Comment: Horray that worked! I was missing the Organization Wide Default set to Private. Thank you!

Comment: @denvergreene Glad I could help!